# Xmpp php prebinding - very long time

Tags: php, xmpp, openfire, strophe

I'm trying to get the session id from openfire server

But to obtain it takes a very long time. More than 50 seconds

```
$jdomain="sitechat.ru";
require("phps/XmppBosh.php");
$boshUrl = "http://{$jdomain}/http-bind"; 
$xmppBosh = new XmppBosh($jdomain, $boshUrl,  '', false, false);
$xmppBosh->connect();
$boshSession = $xmppBosh->getSessionInfo();
print_r($boshSession);
```

Why this problem occurs?

URL: http://sitechat.ru/tests/chat1/prebind.php

Comment: Your URL seems to work for me, execution time ranges from 0.0151s ~ 0.0333s, returns a unique SID + random RID each time.

Comment: Yes, I changed the server. Was Openfire, now Prosody